# AlarmManager fires just after five seconds almost immediately

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android to issue notification after 10 seconds using alarm manager but whatever time I set the notification is fired just after 5 seconds. I've tried reading the other posts from which I understood that I had to set milliseconds from after 1970, but didn't work

Attempt 1

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        alarmIntent.PutExtra("message", "This is my test message!");
        alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", "This is my test title!");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        //alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.Rtc, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);
        Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 21);
        calendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 41);

        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default).TimeInMillis+10000, pendingIntent);
```

Attempt 2

```
DateTime dtBasis = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); // Android times are quoted as milliseconds since start of 1970
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, (long)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToUniversalTime().Subtract(dtBasis).TotalMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard method of getting the milliseconds since the epoch (01/01/1970) within Android is to use the System.currentTimeMillis() method. Therefore you would likely want to try setting the second parameter for alarmManager.set() to be System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000.

The C# equivalent would be to create a DateTime object representing the epoch

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

And then subtract it from the DateTime.UtcNow object to get a TimeSpan object from it

```
TimeSpan tsEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(epoch);
```

Finally, to retrieve the time in milliseconds, cast the timespan's TotalMilliseconds property to a long.

```
long milliSinceEpoch = (long) tsEpoch.TotalMilliseconds;
```

With that you simply add 10000 to that value and that should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: this is really helpful with the c# equivalent i guess

Comment: I still wonder how to set the reminder for a specific time and date

Answer (score 1):

This also helps in a great way

```
Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 20);

calendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 57);


alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis,pendingIntent);
```